# Moving files in a directory using excel file list

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I am new to Python, and I was wondering if there is a way to use Shutil with an excel list of files.

I have a list of 55 files in excel which are placed within sub-folders in a single folder containing 1,500 Files.

Can anyone please guide me in the right direction for how to use the Shutil function with the excel file list to copy these files into one single folder.?

Here are the images for example:

[List of Files that I want to move from one Directory to Another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwsAy.png)

[There are many files in sub-directories as such, I want just the selective files from each of these folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zbh9.png)

Comment: Excel list of files mean what is this a string

Comment: @Nickjones Yes, that is correct. It is the Text string containing file names.